# Recursively counting files and all directories given the directory

Tags: c++, unix, recursion, directory

I've been working on this project and I'm stuck on one of the line in this code.

This basically counts files and number of directories recursively through the directories using `C++` in the `UNIX` environment, but whenever I do the recursive call it has an error saying:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I thought it was because I didn't check the "." and ".." but it wasn't it.

Is there anything wrong with the recursive call?

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void cntFile(string it, int &reg, int &der, size_t &size)
{
    DIR * dirp;
    struct dirent *entry;
    struct stat file_stats;

    dirp = opendir(it.c_str());
    while ((entry = readdir(dirp)) != NULL)
    {
        if (entry->d_type == DT_REG)
        {
            reg++;
            stat(getcwd(entry->d_name,sizeof(entry->d_name)), &file_stats);
            size += (unsigned int) file_stats.st_size;

        }
        else if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR)
        {  

           if(string(entry->d_name) != ".." | string(entry->d_name) != ".")
            {
                string temp;
                temp.append(it + entry->d_name + "/");
                cntFile(temp, reg, der, size);
            }
           der++;
        }
    }
    closedir(dirp); 
}

int main (void)
{
    int reg = 0;
    int der = 0;
    size_t size = 0;
    string it = "/usr/share/";
    cntFile(it, reg, der, size);
    printf("The total number of directories in directory is %d \n", reg);
    printf("The total number of files in directory is %d \n", der);
    printf("The total number of bytes occupied by all files in directory is %zu\n", size);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If your compiler and standards library implementation is new enough, then I recommend that you use [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) for all your filesystem needs. [Recursive directory iteration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator) suddenly becomes very easy.

Comment: Yep that was a mistake!!! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: With `string(entry->d_name) != ".." | string(entry->d_name) != "."` I assume you really mean `string(entry->d_name) != ".." && string(entry->d_name) != "."`? Note the change not only from the bitwise operation but also to logical *AND*. I recommend you learn about [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) about negating conditions.

Answer (score 2):

There is one major problem in how you use [`readdir`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readdir.html) and the structure it returns a pointer to.

From the reference linked to above:

> The application shall not modify the structure to which the return value of `readdir()` points, nor any storage areas pointed to by pointers within the structure.

And yet that's exactly what you're doing with the [`getcwd`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html) call, modify the contents of the structure member `d_name`.

If you want to modify the contents of the name in `d_name` you need to create your own local copy and use that.